# How to run several Spock tests in Eclipse in one click

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, spock

I am working on a Java project in Eclipse. I can run my Spock tests one by one but it is a bit tedious.

My project contains only two directories:

- a *src* directory containing all my Java files
- a *test* directory containing all my Spock tests

I don't use any automation build system.

How can I run all my Spock tests in one click?
Thanks

Comment: How is your project set up? Are these multiple tests across multiple files in the same directory? Multiple directories? What build system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to **Run > Run Configurations** and selecting *JUnit*. You may see one listed as *test* underneath that. If so, click it. If not, right-click the *JUnit* entry in the tree and cick *New*. You should then be able to single-click on the *test* entry and see the *test* directory selected underneath a radio button for *Run all tests in the selected project, package or source folder*. If not, you should be able to select that directory. You may need to specify some settings on the tabs to get it to see the *Groovy* interpreter, etc. but that may already be largely set up (or selectable) if it's working for individual tests.

Then, try right-clicking *right-click* on the *test* directory in the main navigator pane and select **Run As > JUnit Test** (or something along those lines -- it should be the entry you just created). That should run all the tests in that directory.

Not using a build system *may* require some additional configuration in the tabs in the JUnit test config as I mentioned above, but it should be workable (I generally use *Gradle* to manage my builds, and while I can run **gradle test** from the command line to run all the tests, I can also **Run As > JUnit Test** from Eclipse as well).

Comment: yes right-click on the test directory and select **Run As > JUnit** run all the tests. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, and the [Surefire Maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/), that plugin will run automatically:

> all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - "`**/Test*.java`" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that start with "Test".
> - "`**/*Test.java`" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "Test".
> - "`**/*TestCase.java`" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "TestCase".

This is what the [`spockframework/buildsupport/maven/FindSpecsMojo.java`](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/fa6cd927a5c92b54a03567063d3b284fae7ea342/spock-maven/src/main/java/org/spockframework/buildsupport/maven/FindSpecsMojo.java) recommends:

> Plugin that auto-detects and runs all Spock specs in a Maven project.
>
> Specs are run by adding them as `<include>`'s to Surefire's * configuration.
>
> **Note:** This plugin is *not* required for using Spock together with Maven; it merely adds some advanced capabilities like auto-detection of specs.
>   If you decide not to use this plugin, make sure that your spec classes conform to Surefire's naming conventions.
>   By default, these are:
>
> - `**/Test&#42;.java`
> - `**/*Test.java`, and
> - `**/*TestCase.java`